# How to turn on auto-complete in Bracket 31 in *.less file?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I started to use Bracket as my IDE. I like it...

When I edit a CSS file there is great auto-complete, but when I edit less file there is no CSS auto-complete and it would be very useful.

Is there a way to turn CSS auto-complete for less files?

Answer (score 6):

For some reason there isn't any built-in support for this yet but it can easily be hacked in and works quite well.

Open C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets Sprint 32\www\language\languages.json (or whatever path you have it installed to) and scroll down to the `CSS`-key. Then just add "less" to the `fileExtensions`-array, save it and reload Brackets.

```
"css": {
    "name": "CSS",
    "mode": "css",
    "fileExtensions": ["css", "less"],
    "blockComment": ["/*", "*/"]
}
```

For some reason this isn't enabled by default but I haven't discovered any problems with it this far. Works fine with nested declarations which I initially thought would be a problem.

Comment: Note that as of Brackets Sprint 36 this workaround is no longer needed (see below) - code hints will work right out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated answer:*

Autocomplete in LESS files is **now enabled automatically** in [Brackets Sprint 36](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Release-Notes%3a-Sprint-36) and newer (along with the Quick Docs command). The workaround in the answer above is no longer needed.

*Original answer:*

> There's not a way to do it yet. Brackets has a public backlog, which
>   includes a [user story for LESS code hinting
>   support](https://trello.com/c/iHMZSMi6/304-3-code-complete-css-in-less).
>   You can upvote the user story if you sign in with a (free) Trello
>   account.
>
> Brackets [recently added](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/pull/4931)
>   support for CSS-like code hinting in SCSS files, but that was much
>   easier to do. Because the SCSS tokenizer in
>   [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) shares code the CSS one, the two
>   produce very similar streams of tokens, allowing much of Brackets'
>   existing CSS-analysis logic to be reused. The LESS tokenizer, on the
>   other hand, produces different token information that would require
>   larger code changes to support.
>
> But it's certainly doable -- just a matter of prioritization. That's
>   where backlog upvoting and/or pull requests come in :-)